# How to reply UIBarButtonItem highlighted style on UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UINavigationBar` with some `UIBarButtonItem`. I have to set custom view for the first on the left because I want the *x* inside search symbol stay red.

So I created a `UIButton` and using the `initWithCustomView`: method on `UIBarButtonItem`. Now I would like reply the highlighted state of `UIBarButtonItem` (first picture) even on `UIButton` that instead is darken (second picture).

I'd like to not have to create another image for highlighted state.

Ideas ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can lighten your current image using core image filters and use that:

```
UIImage *normalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourNormalImage.png"];
UIImage *lighterImage = [self lightenImage:normalImage];


- (UIImage *)lightenImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:image];

    CIFilter *filter= [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"];
    [filter setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [filter setValue:@(0.5) //Positive as you want it lighter
              forKey:@"inputBrightness"];

    CGImageRef lighterImageRef =[context createCGImage:filter.outputImage
                                              fromRect:filter.outputImage.extent];

    UIImage *lighterImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:lighterImageRef];

    CFRelease(lighterImageRef);
    return lighterImage;

}
```

Comment: I want the image lighter, not darken

Answer (score -2):

When you create the UIButton, before you put it into the UIBarButtonItem, you will need to set an image for the highlighted state. You may not want to do this, but this is the best way to do it. It's also pretty easy.

```
[button setImage:@"lighterImage" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Creating the image should be no more than a few minutes work.

Comment: He has specifically asked for a solution without creating an extra image for the highlighted state